# Route conflict in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I have two routes for web middleware in my laravel app listed below:

```
Route::get('package/{slug}','GetPublicController@tourDetail')
->name('single');
```

And

```
Route::get('/trips/{category}','GetPublicPageController@getBycategory')
->name('getBycategory');
```

The first route works well but second route doesn't. The second route is in conflict with the first route as it tries to get view of first route, causing error and app to breakdown.

Method for 1st route:

```
public function tourDetail($slug)
{
    $tour = Tour::where('slug', '=', $slug)
        ->first();
    $itineraries = Itinerary::where('tour_id','=', $tour->id)
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

    $depature_dates = $tour->datePrice()->FixedDates($tour->id, date('m'),date('Y'))->get();

    return view('public.tour.tour-detail')
        ->withTour($tour)
        ->withItineraries($itineraries)
        ->withDepatures($depature_dates);
}
```

And method for 2nd route

```
public function getByCategory($category)
{
    $query = Tour::whereHas('category', function($r) use($category) {
        $r->where('tcategories.name','=', $category);
    });
    return view('public.pages.category-list')
    ->withResults($query);
}
```

It would be very helpful if anyone could suggest the best approach to resolve this issue. 
Thank you.

Comment: what you mean by route conflict? do you get any errors?  i can't see any conflicts from the posted code

Comment: share your full routes, this look pretty fine

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object ` this is the error that I'm getting while accessing 2nd route.

Comment: And the view is from 1st route.

Comment: what is the url you tried, add your full routes with controller

Comment: Actually no any fault in your URL, an actual fault in your 2nd rout related controller. so please share your controller code first.

Comment: I've added methods from the controller.

Comment: and whats the url you are trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `->get()` on the query in `getByCategory`.